# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized error with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error, connection-string

I am trying to fill a datagrid with data from access, but every time I run this program i get an error saying `ConnectionString property has not been initialized` i have tried everything i know. Can someone please help

```
 Private Sub RefreshData()
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\My_db.accdb"
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        ' open connection '
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    'fill datatable'
    da.Fill(dt)

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    ' close connection'

    cnn.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub BindGrid()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        ' open connection '
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Training log WHERE Runner Name='" & Profile.UsernameTextBox.Text & "'"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Me.RefreshData()

    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: can you try adding the `cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\My_db.accdb"` to function `BindGrid()` ?

Comment: The sql injection vulnerability here makes me sad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the OleDbCommand is never set to use the OleDbConnection object, and the DataAdapter is never set to use the command. Try this, which also fixes several other items that do not conform to commonly accepted practice:

```vb
'Put this module in a separate file
'Any and *ALL* code that talks directly to the DB should go in this module, and use the style of the RefreshData() method below.
Public Module DataLayer
    Private Property ConnectionString() As String
       Get
          Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\My_db.accdb"
       End Get
    End Property

    'I left the name alone so you could match it up to your original code,
    ' but a better name would be something like "TrainingLogByRunner()"
    Public Function RefreshData(ByVal RunnerName As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString), _
              cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Training log] WHERE [Runner Name]= ?", cnn), _
              da As new OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

            '**NEVER** use string concatentation to substitute this kind of value into a query!
            'Had to guess at column type/length here
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 40).Value = RunnerName

            'No need to call Open() for the connection...
            ' the DataAdapter.Fill() method will manage opening/closing the connection
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using 
        Return dt
    End Function
End Module

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = DataLayer.RefreshData(Profile.UsernameTextBox.Text)
End Sub
```